# using apply python pandas to generate multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, apply

I have a function that returns a dictionary and I want to use apply to add new columns to an existing dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from chainmap import ChainMap

# features1 is a dictionary returned from feature_func1
#features2 is a dictionary returned from feature_func2
def applyfeatures(x,datacolumn1,datacolumn2):
    features1=feature_func1(x[datacolumn1],x[datacolumn2])
    features2=feature_func2(x[datacolumn1],x[datacolumn2])
    z= ChainMap(features1,features2)
    return z

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df=pd.read_csv(input_file)
    datacolumn1="data1"
    datacolumn2="data2"
    newdf=df.apply(applyfeatures,args=(datacolumn1,datacolumn2),axis=1)
    merged=df.join(newdf)
```

This gives an error "Other Series must have a name".  This may be due to the way I am returning a dictionary from the applyfeatures. How should I modify it to create a new dataframe based on returned dictionary items.

Comment: Why do you have to use `apply`? Why not just `dataframe['newcolumn']`?

Comment: The feature_funcs are written in a way that they processes each row and create new dictionary items for that row based on datacolumn1 and datacolumn2 and the dictionary is not fixed for every row. Once all the rows are processed, I want to create new columns based on keys across all rows

Comment: i can't test it because you haven't provided a runnable example, but maybe you could try `return pd.Series(z)`

Comment: Yes, converting it to series worked